# Testing attribute set within component constructor

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, mockery

I have a very simple Laravel Component which sets a public property of `$categories`:

```php
public function __construct(Category $category)
{
    $this->categories = $category->children;
}
```

What I would like to do is write a test to ensure that my constructor is populating `categories` with `$category->children` - specifically that `$categories->children` is called. Spying (or mocking) would be nice but I can't spy on (or mock) an eloquent attribute.

```php
it('has the category\'s children', function() {

    $mock_category = Mockery::spy(\App\Models\Category::class);

    $this->component(\App\View\Components\Shop\Breadcrumb::class, [
        'category' => $mock_category
    ]);

    $mock_category->shouldHaveReceived('children')
        ->withNoArgs();
})
```

Results in:

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method children(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_2_App_Models_Category should be called
 at least 1 times but called 0 times
```

I am aware that it seems like I am wanting to test Laravels own Eloquent model. That isn't the purpose of this test. The test is there to ensure that the constructor does not change and if it does, to raise a test failure.

I also have tests in place to verify that `children` returns a correct response so I don't want to recreate that here if possible. It may be that the implementation of `children` changes in the future.

My main thought is that I should wrap the call to `children` in a method so I can do the following:

```php
public function __construct(Category $category)
{
    $this->categories = $category->getChildren();
}

...

it('has the category\'s children', function() {

    $mock_category = Mockery::spy(\App\Models\Category::class);

    $this->component(\App\View\Components\Shop\Breadcrumb::class, [
        'category' => $mock_category
    ]);

    $mock_category->shouldHaveReceived('getChildren')
        ->once()
        ->withNoArgs();
})
```

This feels like I'm uneccessarily overcomplicating my code as I'd need a further test for `getChildren`. If that is the correct method, then happy to do that but curious if there was another/better way.

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to spy a property, that is not possible, you can spy method, but not properties, but still, the property is set/get due to `__get` and `__set`, not literally as `children`, that is why it is not working. The second test/code is better, but the issue is that you feel it is like not right (change code for a test), but sometimes that is the only solution... The "code smell" you are feeling you have here is correct, you should not test this, but have a feature test, where you execute an HTTP request or similar and works as expected, so you do not mock anything

Comment: Yeh, I need to test it for real which will result in duplicated test code but better than duplicated/shimmed "actual" code. Thanks.